# Is it possible to set the click force higher than system settings allows?

Tags: trackpad, plist, magic-trackpad

Is it possible to edit whatever plist contains magic trackpad preferences (MacBook Pro 2023) on Ventura to increase the force required for regular click beyond what the "slider" in system settings allows?  I'd like it if it was approximately 25% "harder" to click and the slider in system settings isn't adaquate. Additionally--where is the .plist governing trackpad settings on Ventura?

Comment: Are you trying to prevent accidental clicking? Remember that the trackpad doesn't actually move, it just senses pressure and the 'click' is a sort of illusion.

Comment: No, I just would like it to require a "firmer" click. My thought is that there is probably a .plist somewhere where there is a value like "regular click" and a value representing the force required for a regular click, let's say "light" is 1 and firm is 10, maybe I can just manually change it to 12. My ideal click firmness is somewhere between the force click and regular click amount of firmness...

Answer (score 0):

You can usually find the .plist file responsible for a given setting by changing the value in System Settings, and then sorting the view of `~/Library/Preferences` by Modification Date.
*(Ideally, sort the view first, then make the change.)*

However, having seen some of the code that Apple engineers write, they would undoubtedly range-check the value, and wouldn't provide a hidden 'up to eleven' capability.